# Ruby mimicking C Integer Data types and union

Tags: c++, c, ruby, emulation

I'm trying to make a Chip-8 emulator in Ruby as my friend has done it before with C++ but I've stumbled across some problems, mind me I have only some knowledge on Ruby whatsoever and I thought this Project would be a good way to improve my skills in this language.

I've read about the Marshal class but I have no idea how to use it whatsoever.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ruby-marshal-0.1.2/docs/Data-Ruby-Marshal-Int.html

So basically the chip-8 opcodes are int16's but I need to get the lower and topmost bits of the instruction so I can correctly interpret it. In C++ he did it with an union and basic int data types as follows

```
struct Instruction {
    union {
        uint16_t opcode;
        struct {
            uint8_t lower;
            uint8_t upper;
        } bytes;
    };
```

*How can I mimick the specific uint8_t and uint16_t types*? I don't mind the union having to trade the union for something else.

Also would this be the best way to use and manage the memory? I actually don't know if the code below is correctly and will compile as I only have access to notepad atm

```
class Memory
    @memory = Hash.new(Array.new)
    @memory[:system] = Array.new(0x200, 0)
    @memory[:rom] = Array.new(0xCA0, 0)
    @memory[:internal] = Array.new(0x5F, 0)
    @memory[:refresher] = Array.new(0xF0, 0)

    @stack = Array.new(0) #Gotta stick with push/pop
end

class Chip8
    def initialize
        @memory = Memory.new
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the high and low byte of a 16-bit word with bitwise operations:

```
high_byte = opcode >> 8
low_byte = opcode & 0xFF
```

The above assumes that `opcode` is already constrained to the range of 16-bit unsigned integers.

And in reverse:

```
opcode = (high_byte << 8) | low_byte
```

The above assumes that `high_byte` and `low_byte` are constrained to the range of 8-bit unsigned integers.

This approach would be arguably better in C++ as well, since the union depends on system endianness (and is technically a non-standard extension in the first place, although widely supported by popular compilers).

Comment: Not only does union type-punning depend on system endianness; it is also technically undefined behavior (though some compilers, such as GCC, guarantee the intuitive semantics as a vendor-specific extension).

Comment: I guess I didn't ask correctly, what I want to do is exactly a way to constrain the integer to a specific range

Comment: @KayleMeta I'm sorry but your question has nothing at all even suggesting that this is the actual question, and I'm actually unconvinced that it even is the question. For example, if you read the opcodes, or individual bytes, from a binary file, the reading part will already have constrained them to the range of the type that you read. On the other hand if you are forming the opcodes yourself, again they are already constrained by being valid opcodes.

Comment: @KayleMeta And if your question is how to take an arbitrary integer in Ruby and constrain it to the range, you can use `x & 0xFFFF` and `x & 0xFF` for 16- and 8-bit ranges, respectively, but you almost certainly don't have arbitrary integers where you would need to do this, and having to do so would indicate that you have an error somewhere earlier.